# Need to run cell twice for the changed code to show output

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, seaborn, data-science

[image: Gif showing my problem]

I've run into an issue where I need to run the same cell twice after making a change. I've included a gif and the code.

In the gif I first change the seaborn style to `darkgrid` and run it, this should show the output as changed to the specified style on the first run, but I need to run it twice in order for the output to change.

Here is the code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.linspace(0,14,100)
for i in range(1,5):
    plt.plot(x,np.sin(x+i*0.5)*(7-i))


sns.set_style("white", {'axes.axisbelow': False})

plt.show()
```

I have tried separating the import lines to a previous cell but still the problem persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your style, before you plot anything . Move the line `sns.set_style` before  `for` loop. It should work.

```
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_style("darkgrid", {'axes.axisbelow': False})
x = np.linspace(0,14,100)
for i in range(1,5):
    plt.plot(x,np.sin(x+i*0.5)*(7-i))
plt.show()
```

Comment: This fixed it. Tysm <3